# Prove that if $v\in V$ is such that $\left< T(v),v\right>=0$, then $T(v)=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, inner-products

**Suppose that of dimension of $V$ is finite and let $T\in L(V)$ be a non-negative linear operator. Prove that if $v\in V$ is such that $\left< T(v),v\right>=0$, then $T(v)=0$.**

My attempt:

I know that if $T$ is non-negative , we can find a linear operator $S$ such that $T=S^*S$, then, we have:

$0=\left< T(v),v\right>=\left< S^*S(v),v\right>=\left< S(v),S(v)\right>=||S(v)||^2$

Can I conclude then that $S(v)=0$ and so $T(v)=S^*S(v)=0$?. Why? I think so but I don't know what conditions have to satify $s$ in order to have $(||S(v)||^2\to S(v)=0)$. Thanks!

Comment: There's no condition, if the norm of a vector is zero, then the vector itself must be zero.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Comment: It's possible to avoid applying the existence of the decomposition $T=S^*S.$ Namely by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have $$|\langle Tv,u\rangle |^2\le \langle Tu,u\rangle\langle Tv,v\rangle$$ Now substitute $u=Tv.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Note that this requires the knowledge that Cauchy Scharz can be applied to positive **semi**definite Hermitian forms

Comment: @BenGrossmann I am aware of that.The proof is the same as for inner product, so I consider that as a standard fact.